# Writing python property shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, properties, decorator, python-decorators

Following is an output from my python 2.7 console. I write similar things in python 3 all the time and it works as expected. So, why am I allowed to do the following reassignment (in python 2.7):

```
>>> class Fola:
...     def __init__(self,a,b):
...         self._a = a
...         self._b = b
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...         return self._a
... 
>>> m = Fola('mlem','blib')
>>> m.a
'mlem'
>>> m._b
'blib'
>>> m._a
'mlem'
>>> m.a = 'plip'
>>> m.a
'plip'
>>> m._a
'mlem'
>>> m._b
'blib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> class Fola(object):
...   def __init__(self,a,b):
...     self._a = a
...     self._b = b
...   @property
...   def a(self):
...     return self._a
... 
>>> m = Fola(1,2)
>>> m.a
1
>>> m._b
2
>>> m.a
1
>>> m._a
1
>>> m.a = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```